# How to pass data from a PHP array into Javascript to build a chart

Tags: php, morris.js

So I'm currently working on building a simple area chart using Morris.JS and PHP.

I have my PHP array which spits out all the data I want currently, and I also have a simple demo of the chart up and running. In that sense, everything is working well.

**The only task left to do now is hook in the PHP array data into the Javascript to pass real data into the chart. As you can see, I need to pass 3 values into the chart (period, read and read). The unread and read is clear, and for the period I'd like to split it by day if possible**

To keep things simple for now - I'm including all the PHP, Javascript and markup on the same page - but of course I aim to eventually pass the data in via AJAX or something, I'm just trying to get a hang on how to actually put the array data into the Javascript.

**How I generate the `$lifeSpanArray` array:**

```
$params = array(
                    'state' => 'all',
                    'sort' => 'newest',
                    'detailType' => 'simple'
                );

            $items = $pocket->retrieve($params, $accessToken);

            $lifeSpanArray = array();


            foreach ($items['list'] as $key) {

                $timeAdded = date('m/d/Y', $key["time_added"]); 

                if ($key["status"] == 1) {
                    $hasRead++;

                    $dateRead = date('m/d/Y', $key["time_read"]);

                    //Push into lifespan array
                    $lifeSpanArray[] = array('timeAdded' => $timeAdded,'timeRead' =>   $dateRead);

                }
                else {
                    $hasNotRead++;
                }

            }
```

**A simple var_dump of the array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/15/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/15/2014
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/15/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/15/2014
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/15/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/15/2014
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/15/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/15/2014
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/15/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/15/2014
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/15/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/15/2014
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/15/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/15/2014
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/14/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/14/2014
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/13/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/15/2014
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/13/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/13/2014
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/12/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/15/2014
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/12/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/12/2014
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/12/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/12/2014
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/12/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/12/2014
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/12/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/12/2014
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/12/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/12/2014
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/11/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/11/2014
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/11/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/11/2014
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/10/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/11/2014
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/10/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/10/2014
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [timeAdded] => 07/09/2014
            [timeRead] => 07/09/2014
        )
)
```

**And then the Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
        Morris.Area({
            element: 'morris-area-chart',
            data: [{
                period: '2010 Q1',
                read: 50,
                added: 100
            }, {
                period: '2010 Q2',
                read: 240,
                added: 400
            }, {
                period: '2010 Q3',
                read: 30,
                added: 15
            }, {
                period: '2010 Q4',
                read: 30,
                added: 100
            }],
            xkey: 'period',
            ykeys: ['read', 'added'],
            labels: ['Read', 'Added'],
            pointSize: 2,
            hideHover: 'auto',
            resize: true
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use json encode. With everything on one page:

```
 Morris.Area({
        element: 'morris-area-chart',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($lifeSpanArray);?>,
        xkey: 'period',
        ykeys: ['read', 'added'],
        labels: ['Read', 'Added'],
        pointSize: 2,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true
    });
```

If you where to seperate this out into seperare files, you could call getdata.php from js, something like this:

```
//getdata.php

$lifeSpanArray = array();//your code for generating array goes here

//remember to set correct content type
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($lifeSpanArray);
die();

//js

$.get( "getdata.php", function( json ) {
  Morris.Area({
      element: 'morris-area-chart',
      data: json,
      xkey: 'period',
      ykeys: ['read', 'added'],
      labels: ['Read', 'Added'],
      pointSize: 2,
      hideHover: 'auto',
      resize: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Great! But to confirm, do I encode the array? i.e. json_encode($lifeSpanArray). I am getting a blank chart, but I assume that's because the period is not set properly.

Comment: @user2656127 are you including the full morris parameters? I only showed element and data in my 1st edit, for brevity. I have now made a further edit with more details, plus an ajax implementation

Comment: Great, thanks for the help - I'll keep investigating!

Comment: @user2656127 Oops, i used the wrong array in my example, changed it now to use `$lifeSpanArray`

Comment: Thanks for your help :) This is the JSON that is returned from getdata.php https://gist.github.com/jamespember/9d6e49157ea9d1b68c48 chart still blank :(